# remove word from url and 301 redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have the following url structure:

> www.domain.com/wordtoremove-title.html
>
> www.domain.com/wordtoremove-title2.html

and want to rewrite and 301 redirect to

> www.domain.com/title.html
>
> www.domain.com/title2.html

so basically is removing the word that comes before the actual title and 301 redirect to the new url structure in .htaccess
How can i do it?
Thank you so much in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file as **first rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^[^-]+(.+?\.html)$ $1 [L,NC,R=301]
```